# create a new worksheet for each column header

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

For each column header, grab the data in each column and create a new worksheet with the data in a single row

To clarify and provide more context, I currently have a table in the format below:

```
Header A | Header B | ...
--------------------------
Data A1  | Data B1  | ...
Data A2  | Data B2  | ...
...
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
For each column header
  Create a new worksheet with the header name
  Fill the worksheet with the following table:
    Data A1 | Data A2 | Data A3 | ... (tldr, for each header, get data and create a table where 
    the headers of the new table are the data relevant to the specific header)
```

Hopefully, this provides enough context to address the problem.

Comment: I'm not too sure where to get started with this, I'm very new to VBA, however have coding experience in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Header Worksheets

- This is just a basic example. The table (one row of headers) has to be contiguous (no empty rows or columns) and it has to start in cell `A1`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateHeaderWorksheets()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1" ' Source Worksheet Name (has table)
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A1" ' Destination Worksheets First Cell
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' minus headers
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim dName As String
    
    For Each scrg In srg.Columns
        dName = CStr(scrg.Cells(1).Value) ' header
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' delete if it exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)) ' new
        dws.Name = dName
        dws.Range(dfCellAddress).Resize(, rCount).Value _
            = Application.Transpose(scrg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value) ' write
        Set dws = Nothing ' reset because in loop
    Next scrg
    
    sws.Select
    
    MsgBox "Worksheets created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```